# zend : use same index for different controllers?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm just learning Zend here:

I have different controllers for different departments to display similar but different information.

Can I use the same index file?  The data that is different is determined inside the controller, so otherwise I'm just going to be copying and pasting the same html file...

Comment: What you want is not clear.
What do you want ?
What have you tried ?
What is the problem ?

Comment: I have a controller like ShoesController, it has an action likes indexAction, and then there is a view in the views directory /views/shoes/index.phtml : so then if I also have another PantsController that has a similar but not exactly the same controller, with view in /views/pants/index.html :  but actually both index files are the same (the data that is different is determined in the controller) - do i have to copy paste the index file or is there some way to reuse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BazBatController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function doSomethingCrazyAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'message' => 'Hello world',
        ));
        $view->setTemplate('foo/baz-bat/do-something-crazy');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

This sets a “message” variable in the View Model, and sets the template name “foo/baz-bat/do-something-crazy”. The View Model is then returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reuse templates. Your templates can be structured however you like, so create a generic `index.phtml` somewhere that makes sense to you, and then in your controller actions just tell the view model to use that template instead of what it does by default:

```
class ShoesController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('some/shared/index.phtml');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

and do the same in your `PantsController`.